# Space between Figures

Tags: spacing

I am trying to find a way how to reduce the space between two figures which are not on the same page. Basically the screenshots explains it:

[image]

On the upper page the space between the Header and the figure is just fine, but on the lower page it is appox. 3 times as big. Why is that? How can I reduce this? Normally I wouldn't questions the page layout of LaTeX but that space causes my text to not entirely fit on the page. If I could reduce this space the text could fit on this one page and not leave 2 widows on the next page (not included in the screenshot).

Here is the code I use:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{chapter/Pictures/M_n_Stern_Anlauf_resized.pdf}  
\caption{Drehmomentverlauf für die Sternschaltung (Kondensator für $s=1$ dimensioniert)}
\label{fig:M_n_Stern_Anlauf}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{chapter/Pictures/I_n_Stern_Anlauf_resized.pdf}  
\caption{Stromverlauf für die Sternschaltung (Kondensator für $s=1$ dimensioniert)}
\label{fig:I_n_Stern_Anlauf}
\end{figure}
```

Thx everyone!

*Edit:*
Thank you for the link. But it did not change anything for me. Maybe because my page is not float only? I added another screenshot which shows the whole second page here:

[image]

My real problem is that the last two words of the last sentence are on the next page which makes no sense. If I change the caption of 2.17 to be one line only then the two missing words come back the way it is supposed to be.

Edit II:
By adding  \pagebreak at the end of the last sentence it fixed the problem for me....

Comment: First try to get rid off all the `!h` that make LaTeX go into *what the duck do i care*-mode. If you don't want floating figures, don't use them  ;-)

Comment: It can because the two figures do not have the same bounding box. You can chack that putting `\includegraphics` in an `\fbox`.